# using jQuery to determine if children of a div have a css class

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

On one of my web pages I'm currently checking whether a css class *isn't* being used, like so:

```
if (!$('*').hasClass("my-special-class")) {
```

The above works but it's checking every element on the page.  In fact, I only need to check within a particular `div` (id = 'mydiv') and its child elements, but am not quite sure what sort of selector to use, and would welcome a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is use the selector itself to compare in an `if` statement

```
if($('.my-special-class').length > 0){
    //element with this class exists - do something
}
```

This will search the DOM for any element with the class `my-special-class`. If it cannot find that element, then the length is returned as 0

Alternatively you can modify your selector if you want to find it within a certain element -

```
if($('#myDiv .my-special-class').length > 0){
    //element exists in #myDiv - do something
}
```

This selector works the same way that any CSS selector works, any children of `myDiv` with the class `my-special-class` will be selected

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$('#myID').find(".my-special-class").length
```

It will return 0, if there are no elements with that class inside that parent div.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $('#yourIDorClass').children().length > 0 ) {
     // do something
}
```

This should work. The children() function returns a JQuery object that contains the children. So you just need to check the size and see if it has at least one child.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use like this

```
$('#mydiv *').hasClass("my-special-class")
```

It will return true if the class is being used by any of the child elements of mydiv,false if not used.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myDiv .my-special-class').length
```

Should do the job :-)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it is checking everything on your HTML page for that class is because you are using `'*'` in your jQuery selector.

If you want to target a specific div with jQuery just alter your code to look like:

```
if (!$('#myDiv').hasClass("my-special-class")) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: it will only check if myDiv has class my-special-class but not for all the child elements having the my-special-class